# VB.NET closing modal window programmatically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a modeal window that I am showing in .aspx.
How do I close this modal window in VB.net programmatically?

Comment: How can you show a modal window on a web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends who closes the window.

Is it the window itself? Then just assign a value to `DialogResult` (`true` or `false`) and the window will hide.

If it is the application who's closing the window, you can use an event that the child window will subscribe to and close itself when raised.

If you want the window to close after a given time, use a timer in this window, and in the handler you can close the window.

Make sure the user understands why the window will close when he did not close it by himself.